# iOS 8 Only Memory Leak with UIAlertController or UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ios8, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I'm seeing a memory leak in iOS 8 in simulator when I do the following with UIActionSheet or UIAlertController. UIActionSheet uses UIAlertController in IOS 8 so the issues are related.

showCameraAction gets called when a button is pressed.  I've removed all of the content from the delegate method and still get the leak in the case shown below.  Am I using UIActionSheet in some way that I shouldn't?  I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.  The same code has no leaks with IOS 7 (in the simulator).

```
-(IBAction)showCameraAction:(id)sender
{

UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo From:"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Phone", @"Flickr", nil];

[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
//also tried  just showInView: self.view
}
```

//empty

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 }
```

Also tried with UIAlertController, with the same result:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Photo From:"
                                      message:@""
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *phoneAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Phone", @"Phone action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Phone action");
                               }];

UIAlertAction *flickrAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Flickr", @"Flickr action")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"Flickr action");
                           }];

[alertController addAction:phoneAction];
[alertController addAction:flickrAction];


[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: Leaks tool screenshot]

Screenshot with trace: https://www.dropbox.com/l/FmnTCd0PvVhuu16BVHZo7p

Comment: I get a similar leak with UIAlertController and UIAlertView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273175/leaks-with-uialertcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277614/uiactionsheet-button-text-not-displaying-properly-in-ios-8

Comment: @Jageen yes.  I'm using ARC.

Comment: @MartinMoizard  Thanks. That's interesting.  It looks like my UIActionSheet is using UIAlertController in the background in iOS 8 too, so they seem related.

Comment: I have run into this problem too! It leaks on the real iPad, and simulator only on iOS8.x See my message in the Apple forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/1099436#1099436

Comment: If you've got a reproducible bug in iOS then please report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use "UIAlertController" in iOS8. 
    And dismiss the alertController object from the presented controller,
    while firing any event by "UIAlertAction" block.

```
UIAlertController  *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title"
message:@"message"
preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction  *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"actionTitle"
style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
//Do ur stuff
[alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                    completion:NULL];
}];
[alertController addAction:alertAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an iOS bug.

See [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem) issue **21005708**, Memory leak in UIAlertController under ARC.

Answer (score 1):

This is no answer, but more evidence for the leak, that exceeds a comment. May it help to find a solution or workaround. The leak seems to be device specific on iPad 3/Retina!

I have made some tests myself by overriding retain and release of the view-controller to show the leak in iOS 8.x

See also: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1099577#1099577

- LEAKY Devices: iPad 3 (A1416), iPad Air Simulator
- GOOD Devices: iPhone 6 iOS 8.1.3, iPhone 4s
  with iOS 8.1.2

AGC is the view-controller. The correct retain count should be 2.

**iPad Retina Simulator iOS 8.1 AND real iPad LEAK**

`// second run ... this time with LEAK by selecting an option
12:56:50.929 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] >>> WILL actionSheet showInView: retain = 2
12:56:50.930 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 3
12:56:50.950 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 4
12:56:50.951 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 5
12:56:50.951 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 6
12:56:50.951 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] <<< DID  actionSheet showInView: retain = 6
12:56:50.998 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 5
12:56:51.042 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 4
12:56:51.042 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 3
// USER dismisses the action sheet with tapping a button (delegate is nil)
12:56:53.257 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 4
12:56:53.257 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 5
12:56:53.258 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 6
12:56:53.258 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 7
12:56:53.258 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 6
12:56:53.259 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 5
12:56:53.612 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 4
12:56:53.612 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 3 // <<<<<<<<<< LEAK should be 2
// the last release is missing, but only iOS system code has executed.`

**iPad Retina Simulator iOS 8.1 AND real iPad, dismiss without LEAK**

`12:54:54.757 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] >>> WILL actionSheet showInView: retain = 2
12:54:54.758 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 3
12:54:54.798 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 4
12:54:54.798 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 5
12:54:54.798 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 6
12:54:54.798 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] <<< DID  actionSheet showInView: retain = 6
12:54:54.845 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 5
12:54:54.891 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 4
12:54:54.891 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 3
// NOW ... dismiss the action sheet without selection (delegate is nil)
12:55:05.643 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 4
12:55:05.644 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 5
12:55:05.644 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 6
12:55:05.644 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC retain == 7
12:55:05.645 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 6
12:55:05.645 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 5
12:55:05.996 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 4
12:55:05.997 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 3
12:55:05.997 SimplySolitaire[27643:473670] AGC release = 2 // this is a correct retain of 2`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest switching to [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html). UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8, so you might try giving it a shot and see if there's still the leak

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that, and xCode didn't warn me either.  However, it appears that UIAlertController is showing the same issue per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273175/leaks-with-uialertcontroller

Comment: Confirmed that use of UIAlertController shows the same memory leak.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem Praneeth? Just wondering if it was another factor, (which is why it still happened after you switched to UIAlertController)