# Memory Leak using an UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instruments, uialertcontroller

I present a simple UIViewController using this simple code

```
@IBAction func addNewFeed(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{

    var alertView: UIAlertController? = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("New Feed", comment: "Titolo popup creazione feed"),
        message: NSLocalizedString("Insert the Title and the Link for the new Feed.", comment: "Messaggio creazione nuovo feed"),
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


    alertView!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Annulla popup creazione nuovo feed"),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
        handler: nil))

    presentViewController(alertView!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When i push a button on my interface i call this IBAction and UIAlertController appears. But when i click on Cancel button to dismiss the controller Leak Tool found a leak as you can see in this image:

[image]

I have tried putting a closure like this in handler parameter:

```
alertView!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Annulla popup creazione nuovo feed"),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
        handler: {[weak self] action in self!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        alertView = nil
        }))
```

but there's always that leak.

Comment: Looks like it is an iOS bug. Check out [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247221/ios-8-only-memory-leak-with-uialertcontroller-or-uiactionsheet/30312928#30312928)

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController`has lots of traps to fall into.

Ash Furrow addresses many of the memory problems in this [blog post](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/). He tried the weak self thing, but settled on using a local variable that is then used in the closure.